# Why can LinkedList be assigned to a List variable?

Tags: java, oop

I am confused about the LinkedList. They do not really make sense to me. Could someone explain to me how it basically works. For example I saw this code (below) and it did not make sense to me. From what I'm guessing a string list (list1) is created and is put in a LinkedList. But what is diffrence between list and LinkedList ?? Thanks

```
List<String>list1 = new LinkedList<String>()
```

Comment: list is interface and linkedlist is implementation of list

Comment: I suggest you begin by reading a basic text on data structures, and a basic text on Java collections.

Comment: Please take a look on this [response][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: `list1` is a *reference* to a List, not a List.  `new` creates a `LinkedList`, initialises it and returns a *reference* to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinkedList is a class implementing the List interface. A interface is not a actual class, its more like a convention/blueprint of what methods that classes implementing them needs to expose.

For example, if you have interface called Shape

```
interface Shape() {
     public void draw(); 
}
```

notice that this contain a method body for draw, rather, its a convention saying all classes which implents this interface must have a method called draw. Now, lets say you have two classes which both implements the above interface

```
class Box implements Shape {
    public void draw() {
        //do actual drawing in this method body
    }
}

class Circle implements Shape {
    public void draw() {
        //do actual drawing in this method body
    }
}
```

You can then cast instances of either Circle or Box into a Shape variable, and safely call the draw method.

Answer (score 2):

This line assigns an empty `LinkedList` object for containing `String`  to a List interface.
The idea of the List interface is, that you later could exchange the `LinkedList` by an `ArrayList` whitout the need to change the rest of your code

E.g:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("element1");
```

list.add() works for both, for `ArrayList` and for `LinkedList`, thats the purpose of the `List Interface`

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.List` is an interface and `java.util.LinkedList` is class which implements `List interface`.

```
List<String>list1 = new LinkedList<String>();
SuperClass(Class or interface) ref= new SubClass(Implementing class/concrete class)
```

The above is **polymorphic way** to create an LinkedList.

Below are some of the characterstics of List:

1. Accepts duplicates
2. Can access using indexes.
3. Maintains Insertion Order

Answer (score 1):

`LinkiedList` implements the List interface so `LinkedList` is a List.

This is the definition of the `LinkedList` Class:

```
public class LinkedList<E> extends AbstractSequentialList<E> implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

As you can see the [`LinkedList` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Object.html) implements the List interface.

Therefore, as `LinkedList` is a List (or a child of List bot not exactly), you can use polymorphism to instantiate a List object like you are saying. The List interface say the behavior of the class that implement this interface, in this case `LinkedList`. Remember that the Interfaces are like a contract, so A**LL THE METHODS THAT ARE DEFINIED IN** List interface **MUST BE IMPLEMENTED** in the `LinkedList class`. In that way List interface has the same methods as the `LinkedList` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is confusing you is the use of generics.

Here it is without generics:

```
List list1 = new LinkedList();
```

This is pretty simple Java code. We're creating a LinkedList object and assigning it to a variable of type List. LinkedList implements the List interface so this works.

Now let's add the generics back:

```
List<String>list1 = new LinkedList<String>();
```

All that is different is that you're specifying what the LinkedList is going to contain.

To put something in the list:

```
list1.add("Something in my linked list");
```